# TLD skipped .... is already defined poping in logs for a Grails deployment in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am deploying multiple Grails (1.3.7) applications in Tomcat 7.0.23. I have my *.jar files in shared/lib instead of WEB-INF/lib. I see the next output in my log files:

```
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
```

Searching in Google I found [a post](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/tomcat-7-tld-skipped-is-already-defined.html) where a solution is proposed.

> Solution Look for duplicates in the server/project jars. In my case
>   spring JSTL has a dependency of Spring standard and eliminating the
>   second solves the problem (The second includes the same TLDs again)

```
>                 <dependency>
>             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>             <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2.0</version>
>             <exclusions>
>              <exclusion>
>               <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard</artifactId>
>               <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
>              </exclusion>
>             </exclusions>
>             </dependency>
```

However, I do not know how I can apply the pointed solution in a grails application. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude transitive dependencies in a Grails app in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    // inherit all Grails' default dependencies except xml-apis
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'xml-apis'
    }

    // dependency on jsoup that excludes transitive dependency on foo 1.0.0
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.6.1' {
        excludes 'org.jsoup:foo:1.0.0'
    }
}
```